# combining dictionary keys based on values and some conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have the following type of dictionaries that I would like to merge on common values. Values are B-Disease, I-Disease etc., where **B** stands for beginning and **I** stands for the end.

```
{'allergen': 'B-Disease'}
{'allergic': 'B-Disease'}
{'symptoms': 'I-Disease'}
{'allergic': 'B-Disease'}
{'symptoms': 'I-Disease'}
{'allergen-specific': 'B-Disease'}
```

I would like to combined the keys (allergen, allergic, symptoms etc.) in such a way that if the key has a **B** value then it should be concatenated with the next entity provided that the next entity also have a **B** value. But if the next value is **I** then that should be ending key to concatenate. These steps needs to be repeated for all the keys.

The resulting dictionary should look like:

```
{'Disease': ['allergen allergic symptoms']}
{'Disease': ['allergic symptoms']}
{'Disease': ['allergen-specific']}
```

or

```
{'Disease': ['allergen allergic symptoms', 'allergic symptoms', 'allergen-specific']}
```

Can anyone help in solving this?

Comment: What is the point of having dictionaries of the same keys ? and have a list of a single element string ?

Comment: @Psidom I get these dictionaries when I apply a NLP model on 12k cells, so in total I get 12k dictionaries and I need to combined these dictionaries.

Comment: I meant the result, why do you need either of these formats ? A dictionary with one key ?

Comment: I need to clean up the results so I can further use this dictionary (keys and values) in another dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your dictionaries are stored in a list.

Try this:

```
dict_list = [{'allergen': 'B-Disease'},{'allergic': 'B-Disease'},{'symptoms': 'I-Disease'},
             {'allergic': 'B-Disease'},{'symptoms': 'I-Disease'},{'allergen-specific': 'B-Disease'}]

disease = {'Disease':[]}
output_list = []


for i, d in enumerate(dict_list):
    if (list(d.values())[0] == 'I-Disease'):
        output_list.append(disease)
        disease = {'Disease':[]}
        continue
    disease['Disease'].append(list(d.keys())[0])
    
    if (i == len(dict_list)-1):
        output_list.append(disease)
```

Output:

```
print(output_list)

[{'Disease': ['allergen', 'allergic']},
 {'Disease': ['allergic']},
 {'Disease': ['allergen-specific']}]
```